# Is there a way to conditionally flip the order of an HStack's contents?

Tags: swiftui

I'm using an `HStack` to layout some elements in my view hierarchy. I'd love to be able to conditionally flip the order of the elements.

```swift
HStack {
  Text("Hello")
  Text("World")
}
```

The idea is that this will either be layouted as "Hello World" or "World Hello" depending on my view's state.

`HStack` itself doesn't provide any functionality for this, but it also appears to be pretty much impossible trying to pull this out of the view itself attempting to use other ViewBuilders, ForEach-based approaches, etc.

The only way I can resolve this is by actually specifying both layouts entirely, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

```swift
let isFlipped: Bool

HStack {
  if isFlipped {
    Text("World")
    Text("Hello")    
  } else {
    Text("Hello")
    Text("World")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is possible generic approach for any pair of views in any container base on using ViewBuilder.

Tested with Xcode 12

[image]

```
struct TestHStackFlip: View {
    @State private var flipped = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                FlipGroup(if: flipped) {
                    Text("Text1")
                    Text("Text2")
                }
            }.animation(.default)     // animatable
            Divider()
            Button("Flip") { self.flipped.toggle() }
        }
    }
}

@ViewBuilder
func FlipGroup<V1: View, V2: View>(if value: Bool,
                @ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> TupleView<(V1, V2)>) -> some View {
    let pair = content()
    if value {
        TupleView((pair.value.1, pair.value.0))
    } else {
        TupleView((pair.value.0, pair.value.1))
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a super interesting approach, thanks for sharing!

Comment: thanks! It is perfect!