# How can I access to views of TupleView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here is a simple way to show what I am trying to do:

```
let test = ("Hello", " world!")

let read = test.0
```

As you can see I defined a tuple and in next line I accessed item 0 of it. I am trying to do the same thing with TupleView like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        CustomView {
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}


struct CustomView<Content1: View, Content2: View>: View {
    
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> TupleView<(Content1, Content2)>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return VStack {
            
            content.0.background(Color.red)          // <<: here!
            
            content.1.background(Color.yellow)       // <<: here!
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

I am getting this error from xCode:

> Value of type '() -> TupleView<(Content1, Content2)>' has no member '0'
>
> Value of type '() -> TupleView<(Content1, Content2)>' has no member '1'

*What I should do for reach to my goal of reading item 0 and item 1 in body? with usage of TupleView*

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62652866/12299030?

Comment: You can use it like this ```content().value.0.background(Color.red) ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
struct CustomView<Content1: View, Content2: View>: View {
    
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> TupleView<(Content1, Content2)>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        return VStack {
            
            content().value.0.background(Color.red)
            
            content().value.0.background(Color.yellow)
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```